# x axis is scaled 0.5 in default python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to draw a simple plot in python, but the x axis is being scaled automatically, I don't want any scaling.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rank = range(2,6)
plt.plot(rank, [0.46,0.567,.347,.87])
plt.show()
```

Here it is the plot:
[image]

I want to remove 2.5, 3.5, 4.5 from the x axis...

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to rescale the plot, or do you want to remove some ticks on the X axis? Those are two different things.

Comment: matplotlib is setting the axis ticks based on your data.  if your data were different, the ticks might be different.  so it isn't the case that it, in general, sets the x-axis ticks in increments of 0.5 by default.  hence, you should rephrase your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
plt.xticks(rank)
```

With this you tell matplotlib which xticks you want to plot